# Page does not refresh data even though it uses no-store cache in Next JS 13.4

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, app-router

I use Next JS 13.4 and using app route. I am fetching the API use option cache `no-store` like this.

```js
export const getBooks = () => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const response = await fetch(process.env.API_BASE_URL + `/books`, { cache: 'no-store' });

  const data = await response.json();

  if (response.status >= 400) {
    reject(data);
  }

  resolve(data);
});
```

I use the data books at `/` URL. I update the data at the `/books/[id]/edit` URL and when success updating, I navigate the page to `/` with `router.replace('/')`.

```
// '/books/[id]/edit'

const editBookMutation = useMutation({
    apiFn: (data) => updateBook(book.id, data),
    onSuccess: () => {
      router.replace('/');
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
});
```

But after navigating to `/` URL, book data does not match the data that should be (The book data still matches the old data). I want to after navigating to `/` URL, API refetch again to gain fresh data from API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is due to the fact that the Next does the "soft navigation" and caches the pages state on the Client, as mentioned in [Next: Linking and Navigating](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating). The page you are navigating to is cached on the client side, so no server rendering and new data fetching occurs at all.

In order to ensure latest data you can either

- fetch the data on the client and handle data caching there with a tool like [TanStack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/overview)
- use the `router.refresh()` inside a `useEffect` hook(see [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router)) on the page to force the new server rendering. It will trigger a new round-trip to server and update the page with new data, only after that the server caching configuration applies.

Comment: I tried the router.refersh() in useEffect. Doesn't refresh the data. I do Cmd + R. I can see data refreshed.

Comment: Hard to guess what is wrong without seeing the code. Either the hook does not run when you expect it to, or the data is cached on the server also (that is a whole different lever of caching described in https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating)